# Поиск подстрок в строке

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм

Есть ли в python встроенные инструкции, которые позволяют осуществлять поиск подстрок в строке?

Строка: `Попробуй этих чудесных и спелых фруктов. Попробуешь?`

Хочу найти: `Поп`

Должен получить: `[0, 43]`. Т.е. индексы всех вхождений в строку.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664850/how-to-find-all-occurrences-of-a-substring

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно использовать алгоритм Кнута-Морриса-Пратта

```
def find_all(source, sub):
    def prefix_func(s):
        pr = [0] * (len(s))
        for i in range(1, len(s)):
            k = pr[i - 1]
            while k > 0 and s[k] != s[i]:
                k = pr[k - 1]
            if s[k] == s[i]:
                k = k + 1
            pr[i] = k
        return pr

    result = prefix_func(sub + "$" + source)  # вместо доллара может быть любой другой не встречаюшийся символ
    return [index for index, element in enumerate(result) if (element >= len(sub))]
```

Работать будет за линейное время от суммарных длин строк. Если вы хотите искать часто по одной строке, то кажется надо будет написать алгоритм Ахо-Корасика.

Comment: Ждал, честно, ждал. Даже лайкну, за то, что знаете КПМ. А может, ещё и БМ?

Comment: Если я хочу искать часто, то скорее всего лучше суффиксное дерево с Укконеном. Ахо-корасик умеет работать только с фиксированным набором строк

Comment: @hedgehogues, наверное лучше этот ответ отметить как правильный ответ

Comment: @hedgehogues, встроенная функция str.find как раз и  [использует смесь «boyer-moore» + «horspool»](https://stackoverflow.com/a/681666/5741205)

Comment: @hedgehogues ступил, Корасика лучше когда наоборот, искомые строки одни и те же

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать регулярные выражения:

```
import re
print([m.start() for m in re.finditer('test', 'test test test test')])
#[0, 5, 10, 15]
```

Comment: Что-нибудь более эффективное бы (=

Comment: @hedgehogues ну тогда наверное только свою функцию писать) В принципе, это несложно. Через s.find('substr') ищем первое вхождение, потом s.find('substr', lastposition) ищем остальные.

Comment: @hedgehogues, по-моему, хороший вариант, а чем он неэффективен?

Comment: @gil9red тем, что это регулярки. И они, по определению, неэффективны. Так как там работают тяжёлые алгоритмы, которые выделяют много памяти, строят конечные автоматы и т.п.

Answer (score 1):

Как на счет такого варианта:

```
def find_all(s, sub):
    res = []
    cur_pos = 0
    for x in s.split(sub)[:-1]:
        cur_pos += len(x)
        res.append(cur_pos)
        cur_pos += len(sub)
    return res
```

---

```
In [187]: find_all("Попробуй этих чудесных и спелых фруктов. Попробуешь?", "Поп")
Out[187]: [0, 41]
```

Comment: Ну, да. Обычно, нечто подобное я всегда и делаю. Но это вымораживает. Хочется однострочник, который будет встроен в язык.

Comment: Вымораживает короткий вызов собственной функции?? Вы их вообще не используете???

Comment: Вымораживает писать это каждый раз. Такого рода функции.

Comment: Ладно, это я придераюсь. Поставлю Вам правильный ответ, окай.

Comment: Напишите модуль со своими функциями и импортируйте его - делов то

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете собирать список вхождений строки, каждый раз обрезая уже учтённое вхождение

```py
def findall(s, substr):
  def searching(s, substr):
    offset = 0
    while s.find(substr) != -1:
      yield s.find(substr) + offset
      offset += len(substr) + s.find(substr)
      s = s[s.find(substr) + len(substr):]
  return list(searching(s,substr))

print(findall('Попробуй этих чудесных и спелых фруктов. Попробуешь?', 'Поп'))
```

Важной частью этого метода является хранение "смещения" строки. Чтобы верно указывать индекс вхождения в изначальную строку, нужно помнить, сколько символов мы уже убрали.
Упростить эту конструкцию можно, убирая вхождения справа - тогда индексы не будут смещаться:

```py
def findall(s, substr):
  def searching(s, substr):
    while s.rfind(substr) != -1:
      yield s.rfind(substr)
      s = s[:s.rfind(substr)]
  return list(reversed(list(searching(s,substr))))

print(findall('Попробуй этих чудесных и спелых фруктов. Попробуешь?', 'Поп'))
```

Результат работы обеих вариантов функций:

```
[0, 41] # да, второе вхождение подстроки находится именно на 41 позиции, а не на 43
```

Comment: О, боги........ yield. А зачем?